# how can limit the action the action in specific namespace?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have create a solution, and add the four projects into it.
 that contains  three mvc site( SiteA,SiteB,SiteC) 
 and a common core class  library(name is core project). 
 now  all of  the mvc sites's Controllers was moved to the core project. 
 and I reference the core project to these mvc sites.
 I try to register routes in these sites.

SiteA:

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AWebDefault",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Core.AWeb.Controllers" }
        );
```

SiteB:

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "BWebDefault",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Core.BWeb.Controllers" }
        );
```

SiteC:

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CWebDefault",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Core.CWeb.Controllers" }
        );
```

the question is :
when i visit the siteA, and how to prevent the user to  vistit the siteB controller or SiteC Controller?
I want to the controller only can be found  in the special namespace. can not search in other namespace. so how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create [action filter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) or [custom action filter](http://blog.falafel.com/custom-filter-asp-net-mvc-5/) and use it before actions or controllers. for this store namespace name and check in filter. if namespace of target action is equal by namespace name then allow access. Another solution is to use Area. To generate a link to a different area, you must explicitly pass the target area name in the routeValues parameter for these methods ([Linking Between Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx)).